# Asking a question in a negative way

Tags: negation

Forgive me for the vague and strange title. I honestly couldn't come up with a better way to ask. As an example to illustrate my question, however, consider the following comic from SBMC (www.sbmc-comics.com)

http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/p-humans

In the comic, one of the participants to the conversation says the following:

> How do you know it doesn't have a rich internal world?

To a non-native speaker, and even sometimes myself (for which English was my first language) this can be very confusing. It seems to me like the question can be interpreted to mean the exact opposite to what the person is asking. In one way, I want to read it as if the speaker is asking for proof that the other person believes the opposite to what they clearly stated.

Is there a term for this kind of question?

Comment: Idiomatically, *How do you know X?* usually implies something along the lines of *You seem to **think** X is true, but I disagree.* It's irrelevant whether condition ***X*** is expressed using negation *(it doesn't have a rich internal world)* or not *(it's vacuous / emotionless / etc.)* So it's often something of a rhetorical question, in that the asker doesn't actually expect the addressee to be able to justify ***X***. But if he *does* genuinely seek an answer, he'd be more likely to ask *How can you **tell** [if] X [is true]?*